# How to change UI text field colour on conditon

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a UIpicker with "pass" or "fail" options to pick, is it possible to change the displayed text colour of "fail" to red (currently black) if the UIText field receives the word Fail?

Im thinking an if statement maybe?

`if textbox1.text = @"Fail"` ....then something?

Comment: The `=` operator ain't for comparison. Neither is the `==` operator in case of objects. Also, are you having problems with: 1. reading UITextField's documentation, 2. Conceiving the basic algorithm for solving this problem, 3. something else?

Comment: I have two questions. 1. Are you wanting to change the color of the text on the PickerView or the TextField when the UITextfield receives the word fail? 2. Do you want it to happen when the text field is done editing?

Comment: Zack..wanting to  Change the text colour when the UI text field receives the word fail

Comment: H2CO3 - Conception of the basic algorithm

Comment: Really? down vote for a sensible question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([textbox1.text isEqualToString:@"Fail"]){
    textbox1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ulas thats what I needed,  Plus one for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color of the text in a `UITextField` by setting the `textColor` to the desired color.

To compare two strings you need to use the `isEqualToString:` method, not the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, using the equal to string method is what i was missing there. Plus 1